# Unsupported Wheel Error when pip installing PyTorch without Conda

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, python-3.7, python-wheel

I have been trying to install PyTorch in Windows 10 for Python 3.7.1

I do not have Anaconda on my machine, and do not wish to install it. I believe I have already satisfied all the necessary prerequisites (CUDA v10.0, NumPy). When I run the following installation command in the admin command line, (found on the PyTorch webpage):

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

I received the following error:

`torch-1.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

I tried downloading the wheel file in my browser, then running a modified command in my downloads directory.

`pip install torch-1.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

I received the same error message. My pip version is up to date and I am attempting to install the appropriate wheel file for my Python version. This problem is unique to others, as I do not want to use Conda to install PyTorch. What is causing  this problem?

Comment: The wheel required 64-bit Python. Verify the your Python is 64 bit: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`. If it's 32 either download 32-bit wheel or reinstall 64-bit Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wheel I was trying to install required 32 bit Python, I had 64 bit Python installed. Therefore, the wheel I was trying to install was not compatible with my Python version.

### Checking Python Version:

I confirmed my Python version using the following command:

`python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

### Checking Wheel Version:

64 bit wheels typically contain `amd64` or similar in their title

32 bit wheels typically contain `win32`or similar in their title

### Switching to a 64 bit Python Installaion:

The default Windows Python installer does not have a 64 bit option. To acquire 64 bit Python, navigate to python.org/downloads/windows/, and select a version that specifies `x86-64` (the other versions are all 32 bit).

---

---

Credit to [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) for the comment that led to this solution.

A Redditor had the same problem [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/8k18tf/wheel_not_supporter_pytorch_installation_on/).